# DocuSign how do you search for the shared envelops that the user has the access to?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign rest api to manage envelopes sent to clients and voiding envelopes.

From this blog: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-void-an-envelope/ 
**You can only void envelopes that you sent or that were shared with you. You have to have the permission to void the envelope based on the specific account from which the envelope was sent.**

So in my application, I suppose I need to check if the envelope was sent by me or was shared with me. How can I code this please? Any request I can use to achieve this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your questions. And upvote all useful answers on the site. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be for you to attempt to void the envelope. If you receive an error response related to ownership of the envelope then that'll tell you that you're not able to void that envelope.

If you didn't send the envelope and it wasn't shared with you, then most of the API calls will fail because of this issue. Eg, you can't look up the tab values of an envelope unless you sent it or it was shared with you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Any specific error code for this scenario please?

Comment: I've figured it out:Error calling Update: {"errorCode":"ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE","message":"This account is not authorized to access the requested envelope."}'